# pandas str in list ,change it's type

Tags: pandas

my data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":['1,2,3,4','1,2,3,6'], "sum": [6,7]})
```

mycode:

```
df['id']=df['id'].str.split(',')

df['nf']=df.apply(lambda x: set(range(1,x['sum']+1))-set(x['id'])  , axis=1)

print(df)
```

i want output

```
             id  sum         nf
0  [1, 2, 3, 4]    6     {5, 6}
1  [1, 2, 3, 6]    7  {4, 5, 7}
```

but it output

```
             id  sum                     nf
0  [1, 2, 3, 4]    6     {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
1  [1, 2, 3, 6]    7  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

i think the 'num' in the list  is actually  str
but i don't known how to easily modify it  by pandas

Comment: jezrael's answer is really good but if you have to do things like that there is already a problem not mentioned. You should not store objects in a dataframe like this if you don't absolutely have to.

Comment: thanks  , in fact ,i read data from a csv , id cloum is str as  1,2,3,4.....

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` for convert values to integers:

```
df['nf']=df.apply(lambda x: set(range(1,x['sum']+1))-set(map(int, x['id']))  , axis=1)
print(df)
             id  sum         nf
0  [1, 2, 3, 4]    6     {5, 6}
1  [1, 2, 3, 6]    7  {4, 5, 7}
```